# Is it possible to boot Linux on a x86 machine with U-Boot?

Tags: linux, boot, bios, bootloader, x86

This is my understanding: BIOS does the basic initialization of the chipset and starts the boot loader which fires up the OS. And most advanced OS like Linux doesn't use BIOS. Also, embedded platforms based on ARM and other architectures use U-Boot for bootstraping the OS.

Given all this: is it possible to bring up Linux on an x86 machine with U-Boot and no BIOS? Do the IBM PC/x86 based machines have an architectural dependency on BIOS to boot up?

Comment: In theory, it's possible. U-Boot [does support x86](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot/u-boot-x86.git;a%3Dsummary). However, you will  probably have a hard time getting it to work on an arbitrary x86 box. (Also, I'm not sure why you'd want to. Maybe look into [coreboot](http://www.coreboot.org/Welcome_to_coreboot) instead?)

Comment: There is even platforms that run U-Boot, like Intel Edison.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Linux can boot directly from a variety of firmware implementations including U-Boot.

> As for loading an OS, U-Boot supports directly booting a 32-bit or 64-bit
> Linux kernel as part of a FIT image. It also supports a compressed zImage.
> U-Boot supports loading an x86 VxWorks kernel. Please check README.vxworks
> for more details.

https://github.com/qemu/u-boot/blob/v2019.07/doc/README.x86

> ## U-Boot on x86 (Updated 15-May-15)
>
> U-Boot supports running as a Coreboot payload on x86. So far only link (Chromebook pixel), Minnowboard, qmemu, broadwell CRB and a few others have been tested, but it should work with minimal adjustments on other x86 boards since Coreboot deals with most of the low-level details.
>
> x86 has been converted to use driver model for serial, GPIO, CPU, PCI and SPI.
>
> U-Boot also supports directly booting a 32-bit or 64-bit kernel, as part of a FIT image. It also supports a compressed zImage.
>
> U-Boot also supports running 'raw' without Coreboot on x86. So far ivybridge, tunnel creek (Atom), Baytrail (Minnowboard Max), Galileo and qemu are supported.
>
> Finally you can run U-Boot on EFI as either an application (which uses EFI services and allows return to EFI) or a payload (where U-Boot takes over the machine and boot from there).
>
> Full instructions are in the source tree at doc/README.x86.

https://u-boot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arch/x86.html

Currently Chromebooks on x86 uses U-Boot to load coreboot

- [How to run Ubilinux / u-boot under qemu (x86)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/205225/44425)

Answer (score 0):

U-Boot supports booting on top of Coreboot, which handles the platform initialisation. This is used on the Chromebook Pixel.

Answer (score 0):

u-boot is a boot loader coming from the embedded devices world.

It cannot initialize hardware the way that BIOS or Coreboot do (using binary blobs coming from hardware manufacturers) because in embedded devices that isn't necessary or it is done by the bootloader in the ROM found inside the SoC itself.

Currently, the opensource alternative to BIOS is Coreboot, or LibreBoot, the version that works without binary blobs. Their supported boards lists are short and usually full of obsolete hardware.
Google uses Coreboot for their Chromebooks instead of BIOS/UEFI.